# From the following sets, which two are not subspaces of $F(\Bbb R) = \{f|f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\Bbb R$ = real numbers

From the following sets, which two are not subspaces of $F(\Bbb R) = \{f|f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\}$

$S= \{f\in F(\Bbb R)|f(1) = 0 \ \text{or} \ f(3) = 0\}$

$T= \{f\in F(\Bbb R)|f(-x) = f(-x) = -f(x), \ x\in\Bbb R\}$ (all odd functions)

$U= \{f\in F(\Bbb R)| f(1)>0\}$

$V= \{f\in F(\Bbb R)|f(1)=0\}$

$S$ and $U$ are True, but I really don't understand what I'm supposed to do or what the initial function means....

Answer (score 1):

In order to be a vector space, a set must be (I) closed under addition, and (II) closed under scalar multiplication. There are also a few technical axioms to verify that addition and scalar multiplication are appropriately defined, which the usual addition and scalar multiplications of functions are.

Let's consider set $V=\{f \in F(\mathbb{R}) ~|~ f(1) =0 \}$.

I. Let $f, g \in V$, which gives that $f(1) = g(1) = 0$. Then $(f+g)(1) = f(1) + g(1) = 0 + 0 = 0$, so $(f+g) \in V$.

II. Let $f \in V$ and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(\lambda f) (1) = \lambda \cdot f(1) = \lambda \cdot 0 = 0$, so $(\lambda f) \in V$.

Therefore, $V$ is a vector space. We would need to apply similar arguments (or see where such arguments fail) for the remaining sets $S,T,U$.

Answer (score 0):

A subset $V \subset W$ is a vector subspace of $W$ over $\Bbb{R}$ when it is a vector space itself. In theory, you should check all 8 axioms, but since we are given that $F(\Bbb{R})$ is already a vector space, 6 of these 8 are immediately true because the addition and scalar multiplication just carry over the 'nice' properties from the ambient vector space (the key idea is: if some property holds for all elements in a set, it obviously holds for all elements in a subset, since they are also elements of the larger set)

So, we only have to check the following two: \begin{align}
&\bullet \;\ \text{For all } r \in \Bbb{R} \text{ and } v \in V: rv \in V \\
&\bullet \;\ \text{For all } v,w \in V: v+w \in V
\end{align}

Take $U$ for instance. If you have any function $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(1) > 0$. Can you multiply $f$ with any real number $f$ so that $rf(1) > 0$? The answer is no, because you can take any negative number for $r$, so that $rf(1) < 0$. Hence $U$ is not a subspace of $F(\Bbb{R})$.

Does this help you enough to do the others on your own?